# How to run the content of another .js file?

Tags: node.js

Imagine I have two .js files, one app.js and the other one socket.js

the content of app.js is this:

```js
const http = require("http");

const httpServer = http.createServer((_, res) => {
  res.write("Hello World!");
  res.end();
});

httpServer.listen(5000);
```

and my socket.js:

```js
const io = require("socket.io").listen(6000);

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("new connection!");
});
```

as you can see there's no need for me to use anything from socket.js inside app.js, but in order to actually run the content inside socket.js I need to do something like `require('./socket.js')` but it feels like it isn't the best solution for this. What's the best thing to do in these kind of situations? ( another example would be starting a database connection like Mongodb using mongoose when you don't need to export the database connection )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in fault here. You actually **need something** from that file, and that is the function that actually bootstraps socket.io, or mongoose in the other example you mentioned. When you run `require('something')` node, loads the file and starts executing the code in it, so the function is actually the whole file.

So, you could just use a `require('socket.js')` in your `server.js` file and get away with it ;) The general conclusion is that you don't need to export anything to use `require`.

What you are asking is impossible. You can't start two separate files in the same process with node. Node only reads **one** file, and then from the `require`'s it proceeds to read the next files. The only way to do that is to have two node processes running... But that is a whole other issue that adds unnecessary complications, and can also be impossible to do in your app. So don't even try it :)

But a cleaner and more consistent pattern you could use, would be something like this:

In a file called `server.js`:

```js
const http = require("http");

const httpServer = http.createServer((_, res) => {
  res.write("Hello World!");
  res.end();
});

function startServer(port = 5000) {
    httpServer.listen(port);
}

module.exports = startServer;
```

In a separate file called `socket.js`:

```js
const io = require("socket.io");

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("new connection!");
});

function startSocket(port = 6000) {
    io.listen(port);
}

module.exports = startSocket;
```

And then in your `app.js`:

```js
const startServer = require('./server.js');
const startSocket = require('./socket.js');

startServer(5000);
startSocket(6000);
```

In this way you abstractify the bootstrap logic of your app, bootstraping each component separately, but allowing you to control the settings (eg: the ports) from one central module.

Comment: by 'need something' I meant that I'm not going to use the imported object for anything inside my app.js, but I get your point and appreciate your cleaner 'pattern'. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to `require` a module without an assignment. For consistency you may want to launch both servers in the same `app` module though. This can be done if you export `io` server from the `socket` module:

```
const io = require("socket.io")();

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("new connection!");
});

module.exports = io;
```

Then call `.listen()` on it in `app.js`:

```
const http = require("http");
const socketServer = require('./socket');

const httpServer = http.createServer((_, res) => {
    res.write("Hello World!");
    res.end();
});

httpServer.listen(5000);
socketServer.listen(6000);
```